# Last Element is not getting stored in to an array in flutter?

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dart

I am trying to store a response from the API to a list, the responses are getting stored but last element is not getting stored in the list.

```
var selectedImage = [];
    if (_image.length > 0) {
          for (var img in _image) {
            var request = http.MultipartRequest(
                'POST', Uri.parse('url'));
            request.fields.addAll({'userPath': "${widget.scanQr}"});
              var process = await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
                  'file', File(img.path).readAsBytesSync(),
                  filename: img.path.split("/").last,
                  contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg'));
              request.files.add(process);
              var response = await request.send();
              print(response.statusCode);
              if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
                  print("The value is $value");
                  selectedImage.add(value);
                  });
                print(selectedImage);
              }
```

The response I get when try to insert 2 images is:

```
[/uploads/jdsfei884ri4h449898/activity/file_1637650234094]
```

the first image is stored but the 2nd image didn't get stored.

Comment: Why don't you get a second response? Do you get an error message? Did you set a breakpoint to find out?

Comment: @nvoigt ,didn't get any error. The second response is getting printed but not getting in to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listen` is not a syncronous method. You do not wait on it to finish, so when your piece of code is done, you have no idea if the stream listeners have already done their work. They *might* have added to the result array, or they might not have.

I suggest you use a method that ensures it did it's job before you move on.

It seems your stream only has one element anyway:

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  const value = await stream.transform(utf8.decoder).first;
  selectedImage.add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace  `selectedImage.add(value);` with  `selectedImage.addAll(value);`

You are getting ArrayList from API, So basically add function add only object and addAll function add your whole list.

Comment: I tried both add and addAll, the result has no change

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion? I see nothing in the question that would indicate an array of locations in the response?

Comment: [/uploads/jdsfei884ri4h449898/activity/file_1637650234094]